# float from char* in c

Tags: c, type-conversion

As practice, I'm trying to make a simple fake shell with 2 simple commands. it is also my first time using strtok. it takes a command(get or set) and a parameter to access(width, height, etc.). my problem is the third argument is a float and I'm wanting to convert it from the char * that strtok returns to the float variable that I'm trying to store it in. I'm at a loss at the moment. I used to be pretty efficient at c, but after a few years of taking a break, I'm amazed at how much of the language I've forgotten. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm not home at the moment, but if I need to I will post the code.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [**atof**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/?kw=atof) is what you're looking for? Takes a char* (from strtok for example) and turns it into a double.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Very quick response. Any way I can +1 you. New to this site, not used to the workings, but thank you again. I was about to beat my head against the wall

Comment: @Toxor You can, and should, accept the answer that best solves your problem. In this case the answer given by Vadim is more complete than the one I gave so you should accept his answer. When, and if, you gain more reputation in the future you can upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

To parse Double, your options are -

1. strtod() - see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) or [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Floats.html)
2. atof() - see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/?kw=atof)
3. sscanf() - see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

atof does not allow to validate the number, it'll return 0.0 if parsing fails. sscanf is a bit cumbersome and the %f formatting may not be present on all systems. Try looking at strtod or strtof (if you want floats).

You could use it like this (txt is your char*)

```
char *end;
float num = strtof(txt, &end);
if (end != txt + strlen(txt))
{
    // This means something went wrong
}
else
{        
    // This means everything is OK
}
```

Comment: Tank you as well. I think the strtof will better fit the purpose

Comment: The error checking is not good. `if (end != txt)` does **not** mean everything went fine. You should use `if (end == txt + strlen(txt))` instead.

Comment: All right, Now my gdb wont run on kubuntu. What is going on. I keep catching a sigsev and cant run gdb to figure it out. How do I post code?